# First Baseline and Last Baseline Properties in UIStackView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uistackview

What effect do the **First Baseline** and **Last Baseline** properties have on the subviews of a `UIStackView`?

Generally, can someone please illustrate the implementation of these values?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Suppose you have a two-line text view (or field or label or button) and a three-line text view, and you add them to a horizontal stack view. Do you want to align their first lines, or their last lines? That's the difference.

`.FirstBaseline`:

[image: .FirstBaseline]

`.LastBaseline`:

[image: .LastBaseline]

Note: I increased the vertical content hugging and compression resistance priorities to 1000 (required) to get this to work properly.

Comment: I added a `UILabel` and a `UITextView` and applied **First Baseline**, but their first lines are not aligned.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstBaselineAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor
```

Represents the baseline for the **topmost** line of text in the view.

```
var lastBaselineAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor
```

Represents the baseline for the **bottommost** line of text in the view.